# Java Jackson select registered module from multiple modules to serialize JSON as string?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a simple java class and want to serialize it to different JSON outputs. e.g:

```
Class User {
    public int id; 
    public String name;
} 

// 2 expected outputs
Version 1 (V1): {"id": "1", "first_name": "A"} 
Version 2 (V2): {"id": "1", "name": "A"}
```

I created 2 customized modules to write to JSON String and they are registered to one ObjectMapper as below:

```
public class ItemSerializerModuleV1 extends SimpleModule {

    public ItemSerializerModuleV1() {
        super(NAME, VERSION_UTIL.version());
        addSerializer(Item.class, new ItemSerializerV1());
    }
}

public class ItemSerializerModuleV2 extends SimpleModule {

    public ItemSerializerModuleV2() {
        super(NAME, VERSION_UTIL.version());
        addSerializer(Item.class, new ItemSerializerV2());
    }
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModules(new ItemSerializerModuleV1(), new ItemSerializerModuleV2());
```

However, **I don't know how to select which module should be used for ObjectMapper when it writes to JSON string**. It only selects the V2 module (the last module registered) with the code below while I also want to write as V1 as well.

```
String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(myItem);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules can be used to extend the functionality provided by `ObjectMapper`, for example, by adding providers for custom serializers and deserializers. You cannot select a module for a particular serialization or disable a module once it's registered.

So you should have two instances of `ObjectMapper` and each instance will a different module registered.

Comment: Yes, I could do that as the simplest way to do, however, not sure the purpose of registerModules() method here. I thought, it can register modules and select one to use for writing as JSON string.

Comment: @BằngRikimaru Modules can be used to extend the functionality provided by `ObjectMapper`, for example, by adding providers for custom serializers and deserializers. You cannot select a module for a particular serialization or disable a module once it's registered.

Comment: See also https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/3089#issuecomment-817230358. "it is true, one can only register a single serializer or deserializer for given type [...] This is by design"